# PHP Form not showing proper error message

Tags: php, forms

Does anyone have any idea as to why this is showing the error message? I have tired empty and boolean test.

Thanks!

```
<p>You have nearly a full tank of fuel at <?php echo $intFuelGallons ?> gallons.</p>
    <p> Do you want to top off your tank?
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="TankTopOff" value="Yes" id="TankTopOff">
        Yes</label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="TankTopOff" value="No" id="TankTopOff">
        No</label>
    </p>
    <p><?php echo $varWornTires ?> of your tires are worn. Do you want to replace any of them?</p>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="TireReplace" value="Yes" id="TireReplace">
      Yes</label>
    <label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="TireReplace" value="No" id="TireReplace">
      No</label>
    <label>
 <?php
 if ((($_POST['TankTopOff'])!=="No") || (($_POST['TankTopOff'])!=="Yes")) {
 $errorMessage .= "<li><h5>You forgot to choose if you want to top off your tank! " . ($_POST['TankTopOff']) . "</h5></li>";
};
 if ((($_POST['TireReplace'])!=="No") || (($_POST['TireReplace'])!=="Yes")) {
 $errorMessage .= "<li><h5>You forgot to choose if you want to replace any tires! ". ($_POST['TireReplace']) . "</h5></li>";
};
?>
```

Comment: first of all, replace `errorMessage` with `$errorMessage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
if(empty($_POST['TankTopOff']))
```

instead of

```
if ((($_POST['TankTopOff'])!=="No") || (($_POST['TankTopOff'])!=="Yes"))
```

and do the same with TireReplace

Answer (score 3):

The boolean expression will never be false:

```
(($_POST['TankTopOff'])!=="No") || (($_POST['TankTopOff'])!=="Yes")
```

translates as `EITHER the TankTopOff is something else than "No" OR TankTopOff is something else than "Yes"`; which is always true.

Probably you just need to replace `||` with `&&` (or even better - "and", if as suggested by [some PHP framework developers](http://fuelphp.com/docs/general/coding_standards.html#/comparison_logical)).

Comment: Both worked but I liked empty as it was less complicated. I have no idea why it didn't work the first time... Might be too close to it!

Answer (score 1):

You should do

```
 <?php
   if ($_POST['TankTopOff']=='') {
        $errorMessage .= "<li><h5>You forgot to choose if you want to top off your tank! </h5></li>";
    };
   if ($_POST['TireReplace'])=='') {
        $errorMessage .= "<li><h5>You forgot to choose if you want to replace any tires!</h5></li>";
    };
  ?>
```